# Instantiating class using tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python, class

I just started OOP in my python course. I'm trying to write a little program which creates class called 'Employee', very simple with just a name and a surname. The thing I am trying to do is the following: I have a function which asks a name and a surname and returns a list of tuples, consisting of a name and a surname. I don't know how many names the user will put in, so I don't know how of how many tuples the list consists. My question now is how to write a function that creates a class 'Employee' for each tuple.

This is the program:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        print 'Employee created!'
        print 'Welkom %s %s'%(name, surname)

def create_employee():

    x = []

    while True:

        y = raw_input('Name: '),raw_input('Surname: ')

        answer = raw_input('Do you want to add another employee? Yes or No ')

        if answer == 'Yes' or answer == 'yes':
            answer == True
        else:
        break
```

I tried the following: `y = Employee(raw_input('name '), raw_input('surname '))`
This returns a list of objects but then I don't know how to reach them. They are in the list, and if i call the list, I just get a list with the locations of the objects, but I don't know how to call functions on them.

I have been stuck on this for two days now. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading `name` and `surname` into a tuple called `y`. What I think you want to do is create an instance of the `Employee` class from the tuple `y`, like this:

```
employee = Employee(*y)
```

That creates an instance of `Employee` and passes name and surname to the constructor `__init__()`.

So your `create_employee()` function will look like this:

```
def create_employee():
    x = []

    while True:   
        y = raw_input('Name: '), raw_input('Surname: ')
        employee = Employee(*y) # Create an instance of Employee from input
        x.append(employee)      # Save object in a list for future use

        answer = raw_input('Do you want to add another employee? Yes or No ')

        if answer == 'Yes' or answer == 'yes':
            answer == True
        else:
            break

    return x   # Pass the list of objects back when user is finished
```

Now you need to use the list of `Employee` objects you have created.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = create_employee()
    for employee in x:
        print employee.name, employee.surname
```

Output is

```
Name: Joe
Surname: Bloggs
Employee created!
Welkom Joe Bloggs
Do you want to add another employee? Yes or No No
Joe Bloggs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't understand what you mean. Where do I add your comment in the code? And does it work if I wanna add more than one employee, but don't know how many?                                                   (The method was indeed an indentation error)

Comment: See the expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now. This helped me very much!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you.